# Name for the number of edges we can delete so the graph is still connected

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a connected finite graph. I was wondering what is the word in English for the maximum integer $r \geq 0$ such that there exist edges $a_1, \ldots , a_r$ such that $X - a_1 - \ldots - a_r$ is connected. I would call it the *"connectedness degree"*, but I can't find either this name or the concept itself in the internet or Hatcher's.

**Edit.:** Call this "connectedness degree" $c(X)$ for a connected finite graph $X$. If $\chi (X)$ is the Euler characteristic, there's a important formula (very useful to compute the fundamental group of the graph) $$\chi (X) + c(X) =1$$

Comment: I don't think there's a special name for this, because there's a trivial formula for this. The minimum number of edges for the graph to remain connected is $n-1$, where $n$ is the vertex count; every connected graph has a spanning tree. Thus if $e$ is the edge count, the maximum number of edges that can be removed is $e-n+1$.

Comment: As answered below there is no name for maximum number of edges. Perhaps you are interested in the minimum number of edges instead, i.e. edge connectivity.

Comment: @Shahab Indeed we are saying the same thing. Maximum number of edges we can delete so that it remains connected  +1 == minimum number of edges so that it disconnects

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that number has a fancy name, because it is always
$$ |E|-|V|+1 $$
for a connected graph. When you have removed a maximal amount of edges, what is left is a *spanning tree*, and the number of edges in a tree is exactly one less than the number of vertices.

Comment: That's exactly the formula I added in my edit -in fact I should have added before publishing. Does "edge connectivity" make sense for you, as indicated below?

Comment: @Minkowski: I wouldn't use a name that suggests "connectivity", which would be misleading because it doesn't actually depend on the shape of the graph. Someone might even misunderstand it to mean the largest $k$ such that the graph is $k$-edge-connected. You could call it something like "edge surplus", I suppose.